# Salesforce Unique ID accross Pods

Tags: salesforce-id

First of all I know its a common question but I haven't found a concrete description yet.

As we know Salesforce IDs have the following structure

i.e 001-20-0-0000BQjF7-AAL

**001 - Object Prefix (Accounts)**

**20 - Pod Id (EU0)**

**0 - Reserved**

**0000BQjF7 - Unique alphanumeric identifier (base62)**

**AAL - Case-insensitive**

I want to focus on the alphanumeric ID (base62) part of the ID.

Is this ID unique across all pods or does each pod has a range of 62^9 unique IDs? (Sandboxes are an exception)

Theoretically if we put it into test, is any of the following scenarios possible?

| ID | Change |
| --- | --- |
| 001-20-0-0000BQjF7-AAL |  |
| 002-20-0-0000BQjF7-AAL | same pod different sobject |
| 001-D0-0-0000BQjF7-AAL | different pod same sobject |

Comment: What's the problem/issue behind the question, or is just an inquiring minds question :)

Comment: @Girbot yeah its more like a general question rather than a specific issue :) Most information available regarding this subject is tackle from the Org perspective rather than the whole Force.com platform

Answer (score 2):

Each pod keeps track of the unique ID values handed out per key prefix independently. It is therefore highly that, at some point, the ID values 001500000012345AAA and 001600000012345AAA have both existed at some point. They may have been burned up by a unit test, or the record may have been since deleted, etc, but those ID values definitely did exist at some point.

Comment: so its safe to assume that each pod has its own range of unique IDs in the following sense ?
<<3 digits prefix>> - 50 - 0 - <<62^9>> - AAA

So theoretically if we assign the whole range of 62^9 digits on a single Object in a single Pod (lets assume no unit test or deletes), there wont be any Unique ID left to create a record for another Object ?
001500<<000000000 - ZZZZZZZZZ>>AAA

Do you may know what happens to burned IDs, do they become available again after some time ?

Comment: @GiannisDim We don't know. They won't run out of any Id's anytime soon. Even Account, which is probably the most heavily used Id type, only has about 0.0000001% of the Id values used on one of the oldest servers they still have (I have an account on na3), and Salesforce has been running for 22 years. Presumably they have a plan, either adding another prefix, consolidating Ids, etc, but they shouldn't need to do so anytime before 2100 AD.